# Intermittent RequireJS Load Error

Tags: javascript, module, backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd

I have a rather large Backbone.js project that uses RequireJS. As the project size grew ("size" here referring to the number of separate module files), intermittent errors started cropping up. Most of the time, it's an object error:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

Occasionally, it complains about a module not being loaded.

These errors disappear once the project is run through the r.js optimizer. They only happen when RequireJS is loading the individual modules.

Which brings me down to my question - does RequireJS start having issues with modules loading in time when the number of modules reach a certain number?

Comment: I doubt that this is really a RequireJS issue, but rather some browser-related one. Does it fail consistently across different browsers? Does RequireJS log any problems, such as timeouts when loading scripts, to the console?

Comment: I've seen it the most in Chrome, though I've also seen it occur in Firefox as well. There are no RequireJS logs or errors. The error that is occurring is when I try to instantiate a Javascript function (prototype) exported from a loaded module. It is throwing because the module doesn't seem to be properly loaded, since Javascript doesn't recognize it as a function. This is when the error actually happens - which is only sometimes. The rest of the time, the code executes perfectly fine. Regardless, there's no RequireJS timeout error.

Comment: Sounds like an order of load/initialization issue to me. Note that you can get undefined references if you have circular dependencies in your code, I would look for them first. We have a project with several hundred JS files loaded by RequireJS and no such problems whatsoever (neither in Chrome nor other browsers).

Comment: Yeah, I've run into circular dependency issues before, but what's throwing me in this case is that the issues are intermittent. And solved by the optimizer. In the past, circular dependencies consistently threw errors. This doesn't. I've also tried placing module loading earlier, rearranging loading, and forcing loading flow with the !order plugin, all with no success. Do you have any suggestions for other potential issues that could cause intermittent problems like this?

Comment: Even though the errors are intermittent, when they occur do they always happen in the same few files or locations? I'd maybe add some sanity checks to fail early (e.g. at the very beginning of the modules), thereby making it easier to find the cause. When using the optimizer, all things are loaded in one go. Loading on demand exposes your app to order problems as mentioned, but also to issues when you do resolve modules on the go in the code (e.g. through `require("MyModule")` or `require(["MyModule"], function(myModule) { ... })`.

Comment: Absolutely sounds like a sync/race condition issue to me as well. I have/participate in a very large Backbone project as well, and no degrading on RequireJS part has ever taken place.

Comment: Yes, when the errors do throw, they seem to throw consistently from the same places. The most common error is an `object is not a function` error, which throws when one Backbone view tries to instantiate another Backbone view: `this.header = new HeaderView()`. HeaderView is required at the top: `HeaderView = require('views/HeaderView')`. I've moved the instantiation to both sooner and later - no fix. I've moved the require to earlier and tried with !order - no fix. Can you point me in any directions of possible causes? If it is a sync/race condition, how can I address it?

Comment: Does your module (the one you are trying to instantiate) really return a function?

Comment: Yeah - and as I've said, this issue is intermittent, so most of the time everything works perfectly fine. That's what's tripping me up - the code is, well, *fine*. But to be more specific, the module returns a function that has multiple functions added to its prototype. For sake of clarity, the module is compiled CoffeeScript. So what the module is returning is a CoffeeScript "class", but a CoffeeScript class is nothing more than a function with its prototype added to.

Comment: Could it be a module load timeout issue? Is anything dumped to console? Can you try turning on 'break on exceptions' and see what the initial failure condition is?

Comment: I ran into this same issue, because i had some inline code that used "require(['app']), below my <script> tag that had data-main module of 'main', which had the require.config code in it and initialized the 'app'.  Sometimes the data-main module would be loaded first and initialize the app and things would work fine, sometimes the inline javascript would try to get 'app' first and things would be broken. As I learned, its really asynchronous and you have to assume as much.  Rewriting my inline code as a function I could call back from my main code worked out.  Only 1 point of entry = best.

Comment: @Ben Good suggestions - unfortunately, they don't really apply to my situation. RequireJS is my only point of entry into this app. Plus, it seems like in your situation, the app would fail even after optimization as well, which mine doesn't. It has never thrown these errors after being run through the r.js optimizer. And there aren't any module load timeouts being thrown either. No RequireJS errors logged. Very odd and quite frustrating.

Answer (score 9):

This Issue seems to be addressed in the forthcoming require.js 2.1 release. See here:

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/478

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely a bug that I have encountered a lot over the last few days. Loading one module can cause a second completely unrelated module in a different part of the app to become undefined where it worked perfectly before. I have used RequireJS a lot - this is not a script loading or circular dependency issue. At first I encountered the error most often when requiring a text file in a 2nd-tier view that gets iterated quite a few times (1800+):

```
domReady -calls-> new View1() -iterates-> new SubView() -depends-> text!template
         -calls-> new View2() --> undefined!
```

This would cause a completely unrelated module elsewhere to become undefined. I worked around it for a while by integrating the SubView functionality into the View module.

```
domReady -calls-> new CombinedView1() -depends-> text!template
         -calls-> new View2() --> ... all good ...
```

As the project has grown I have hit the wall again and really need to find a way to fix it. Including more modules causes previously defined ones to become undefined at random. Require throws no errors and neither does the browser. I'm not using CoffeeScript or anything like that either.

I have taken some time create a version of my application that has the same module and dependency structure with the dependent Views, Models and Collections stubbed out. This works perfectly fine, so I can only assume there is some kind of memory issue? However Chrome never throws any errors either.

I think my next step will be to pad out my skeleton application with some memory-consuming loops and see what happens: I will let you know how it goes.

Using Require v2.0.1, so no order plugin - dependencies and packages are all configured using the shim config directive.
Non-AMD modules loaded:

- Backbone
- Underscore
- jQuery
- Mustache
- Leaflet
- Bootstrap

P.S. Apologies if this is not in the right place. I thought it would be better as a comment but I honestly can't see the comment button anywhere.

**Update:**
This dependency structure breaks consistently:

```
Main
  - View 1
      - text!...
      - View 2
         - text!...
```

Substituting the text with empty strings works fine every time:

```
Main
  - View 1
      - View 2
```

So why does waiting for the text to load cause View 1 to become undefined when it is explicitly set as a dependency in the Main module? Surely Main should not be called until everything it is dependent on is loaded?

Comment: I got exactly the same problem. also see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/requirejs/Eym3R08Bmmg

Comment: Apparently, also requiring the `text!...` dependency of View 2 in View 1 makes the module load properly again. Not beautiful, but it works.

Comment: Good to hear that I'm not crazy - it obviously can't be circular dependency issues if it is intermittent. Clearly something deeper going on. I'll be following the Google Groups thread you opened as well, @SteveBeer.

Answer (score 5):

I've been fighting with the same issue the last days and this is what I found out:

Apparently, a nested dependency structure requiring templates via the text.js plugin can cause a race condition that lets the top level module not be ready when requirejs thinks it is. I only ran into this problem when I had several nested module dependency structures of this type:

```
Router
  -> View1
    -> text!.../view1.html
    -> View2
      -> text!.../view2.html
  -> View3
    -> text!.../view3.html
    -> View4
      -> text!.../view4.html
  -> View5
    -> text!.../view5.html
    -> View6
      -> text!.../view6.html
  -> View7
    -> text!.../view7.html
    -> View8
      -> text!.../view8.html
```

Having this structure, I got TypeErrors like 'View1 is not a constructor' when the router tries to instantiate the views.

Also requiring the templates of the nested views in the top level views solved the problem for me:

```
Router
  -> View1
    -> text!.../view1.html
    -> text!.../view2.html
    -> View2
      -> text!.../view2.html
  -> View3
    -> text!.../view3.html
    -> text!.../view4.html
    -> View4
      -> text!.../view4.html
  -> View5
    -> text!.../view5.html
    -> text!.../view6.html
    -> View6
      -> text!.../view6.html
  -> View7
    -> text!.../view7.html
    -> text!.../view8.html
    -> View8
      -> text!.../view8.html
```

I don't really know how require.js works, but this looks to me like those nested text! calls aren't regarded when some 'ready' flag for the parent module is set.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like what is causing the issue. I'm also using quite a lot of text! calls, so it looks like the issue is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have

- shim configured http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim
- 'waitSeconds' property and
- http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

Hope this helps