# RequireJS works inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

When I press F5 to reload my app sometimes throws errors  and sometimes it does not.

I am debugging with Chrome. Sometimes the console reports this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: unit_directionals is not defined
```

sometimes throws that a reference is not defined like in this case for jquery:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not define"

What can be wrong if i have defined the files in the correct way?

**this is the code I have in the main.js pointed in the main index html:**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths:{
        app:'../app',
        models: '../app/models',
        views: '../app/views'
    }
})

requirejs(
    [
        //load lib in this order
        'underscore', 'handlebars', 'jquery','backbone', 'uri',
        //load models, views...
        'app/models/items.model', 'app/models/results.model',
        'app/views/items.view', 'app/views/results.view',
        'app/index'
    ],
    function(jQuery,$,_....) {
        //init app
    }
);
```

Comment: Looks like the same issue I posted over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959095/intermittent-requirejs-load-error. There's also a thread on Google Groups about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/requirejs/Eym3R08Bmmg. We're still trying to find a resolution.

Comment: If you find a solution please let me know bro, will really aprettiate it!!!

Comment: We had this issue.  Turned out jQuery was included twice causing random script errors on F5.  jQuery was included Once in require, and another in a script tag on an MVC partial view.  We removed the jQuery script tag from the view and it's working ok now; can F5 all day long.  What a headache!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

requirejs loads modules async and they can load out of order -- they are not guaranteed to load in the order specified in the require call. If the script is an AMD module, and calls define() with its dependencies, this is not a problem.

However, if the script just uses browser globals and implicit dependencies, like backbone and probably handlebars, then the [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) is needed to properly express the dependencies and export value.